# "Succede che" + indicativo o congiuntivo?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjunctive-mood

Non riesco a capire quando si deve usare l'indicativo e quando il congiuntivo dopo l'espressione "succede che". Cercando su Internet, ho trovato alcuni esempi di uso sia dell'indicativo che del congiuntivo:

http://en.bab.la/dictionary/italian-english/succede

> *E succede che si sta lentamente espandendo all'esterno di quella forma originaria.*

http://books.google.es/books?id=bjRXDwWyuekC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=%22succede+che%22

> *Succede che cambia tutto, e l'indice non è più un valore indicativo per dedurre il carico.*

http://books.google.es/books?id=XiEy3QhkS1MC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=%22succede+che%22

> *Succede che il motivo delle guerre sia ingiusto, p. es., per la mancanza di una giusta causa per scatenare una guerra.*

http://books.google.es/books?id=fi0lzmlyJgAC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=%22succede+che%22#v=onepage&q=%22succede%20che%22&f=false

> *Succede che un uomo venga indagato per un delitto mesi e mesi dopo che il fatto è accaduto.*

Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi scuso perché questa è più un'opinione che una risposta argomentata, che avrebbe bisogno di fonti.

Succede che costruzioni come questa possono reggere entrambi i modi verbali. Spesso sarà preferibile l'indicativo, se veramente si parla di qualcosa che “succede”, e non che si ipotizza, o spera, o immagina. Ma la locuzione “succede che” si può usare anche con una sfumatura molto vicina a “può succedere che”, e allora ha senso usare il congiuntivo. Anzi, è proprio la scelta del modo verbale della subordinata che chiarisce in che senso stiamo usando quel “succede che”.

(Poi succede anche che qualcuno usa il congiuntivo per un automatismo da scuola media per cui nelle subordinate che suonano in quel modo si usa il congiuntivo senza pensarci troppo su...)

Noto un fenomeno analogo, per esempio, con “il fatto che”. Spesso regge l'indicativo, perché si parla proprio di *un fatto*. (Da un esempio in rete: «Il fatto che sei mio fratello non ti autorizza a trattarmi così».) Ma a molti “suona meglio il congiuntivo”, oppure temono di passare per ignoranti se non lo usano, ma a volte lo si usa a ragion veduta perché si parla sì di un fatto, ma ipotetico: «Il fatto che ci siano macchie visibili non significa che il pavimento non sia pulito», che è un po' come dire «Anche se fossero visibili delle macchie, non significherebbe etc.».

(Prendo gli esempi del fratello e delle macchie da [questa discussione in rete](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1639043) che non ha alcuna autorità, ma dà spunti interessanti.)

Comment: “Succede anche che qualcuno usi” se, per esempio, vuoi far intendere che non è così frequente. Non vedo qui un “automatismo da scuola media”: forme alternative con sfumature diverse, come del resto dici tu stesso.

Comment: Infatti, ho messo l'“automatismo” tra parentesi come causa di qualche occasionale ipercorrettismo.

Answer (score 1):

Io sono uno di quelli cui suona meglio il congiuntivo dopo l'espressione "succede che"... ma non sono un esperto di lingua italiana, quindi il mio è solo un parere personale. Comunque mettendo il congiuntivo non sbagli di certo...

Answer (score 0):

In realtà, la grammatica detta regole chiare in questo come in altri casi in cui troviamo coinvolti i verbi al modo congiuntivo, per semplicità:

> 1. **in presenza di periodi ipotetici, in cui la situazione è (ancora)
>    incerta, il congiuntivo è d'obbligo.**
> 2. **mentre di fronte a realtà fattuale innegabile, è corretto
>    l'indicativo.**

Nel primo caso (ipotesi, probabilità, incertezza o anche per esprimere un opinione non necessariamente condivisa da tutti):
**Corretto:** Fermando una lista di sospettati succede a volte che **sia** possibile arrestare il vero colpevole.
**Errato:**  Fermando una lista di sospettati succede a volte che **è** possibile arrestare il vero colpevole.

Nel secondo (certezza inconfutabile, fatti già avvenuti e noti):
**Corretto:** Sulla Terra, lanciando un oggetto dall'alto succedde che tale oggetto **cade** a causa della gravità.
**Errato:** Sulla Terra, lanciando un oggetto dall'alto succedde che tale oggetto **cada** a causa della gravità.

Considerazioni sul linguaggio parlato correntemente in Italia sono corrette da un punto di vista pratico (in fondo qualsiasi lingua viva è e sarà sempre in perenne evoluzione e cambiamento), ma esulano dal rigore grammaticale.

Comment: Non sono così certo che le formulazioni da te indicate con 'Errato' siano realmente errate.

Comment: Non mi è chiaro il tuo esempio su «Comprando un biglietto della lotteria succede a volte che è/sia possibile vincere». A parte che è una frase un po' forzata, e non penso che ci si esprimerebbe spontaneamente così, è una “realtà fattuale innegabile” che “è possibile vincere” se si compra un biglietto (a meno di non voler dire che gli organizzatori della lotteria truffino i partecipanti non assegnando a nessuno il premio).

Comment: Hai ragione DaG, l'esempio della lotteria è stata in effetti una forzatura, l'ho cambiato ora. Questo nuovo esempio mi sembra più naturale, tu che ne pensi?