# Is this verb in subjunctive?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

Could you please help me out with this subjunctive problem I've got?

Is the verb *tornare* in this sentence in subjunctive?

> Aspetterò che torni come aspetto il sole

If yes, then why isn't the verb *aumentare* in the next sentence also in subjunctive?

> Ti giuro che l’attesa aumenta il desiderio

For context, both sentences are taken from the lyrics of a song.

From what I studied I know if there are different subjects in the dependent and independent clauses, subjunctive kicks in. Maybe you could provide some way I can distinguish when to use subjunctive in similar cases (besides the conjunctions, some verbs).

Thank you!

Comment: “I know if there are different subjects in the dependent and independent clauses, subjunctive kicks in”: Someone will certainly answer the question itself, but for now know that this, phrased in general like this, is simply, utterly false. There are several different dependent clauses, and in many of them you never use subjunctive. Just think _Mi sbrigo perché è tardi_ or _So che hai ragione_.

Comment: I really wish I were able to write a good answer explaining the rules for the usage of subjunctive, but they are really really hard and I am often uncertain myself. I might write a brief primer later today if I have the time, but it'll be very incomplete. If anyone feels like writing a good one, I'd love to read it :).

Comment: I took the liberty of improving a bit the formatting. Feel free to revert it, if you prefer to do so.

Answer (score 8):

The subjunctive is thorny topic: even extremely well-educated people use it incorrectly from time to time. However [*don't panic*](https://youtu.be/xS358WbnS_k?t=106). By remembering a few rules you can get as good as most native speakers. Which, admittedly, is more of a criticism of most native speakers but still, it's not bad uh?

A small caveat: to every "rule" I list here there are a lot of exceptions, as well as additional complex rules I haven't mentioned. I hope however that this primer will help you to orient yourself in this beautiful mess that is Italian subjunctive usage. Let's get started.

---

The general rule is that the subjunctive in a subordinate expresses a **lack of objectivity in the situation**. Some sort of lingering doubt that what's expressed by the clause is not, in fact, certain. Let's see a few examples where this is a bit more clear cut.

In a subordinate sentence, the subjunctive is mandatory in the following situations:

- With verbs expressing will, desire, doubts, feelings or opinions:

  > Voglio che stasera vi divertiate.
  >   Mi piacerebbe che veniate a trovarmi!
  >   Non so se questa sia la decisione giusta.
  >   Sono felice che tu sia tornato da me.
  >   Credo che questa sia la risposta giusta.
  >   Giovanni pensa che sua madre abbia sempre ragione!
- With clauses expressing a *goal* or an *allowance*

  > Il pittore lavorò a lungo affinché il quadro fosse perfetto.
  >   Nonostante la situazione sia dura, bisogna cercare la felicità nelle piccole cose.
- When doing *general comparisons*. However, when doing limited or specific comparisons, the indicative is used.

  > È il libro più interessante che io **abbia** mai letto.
  >   È il libro più interessante che **ho** letto quest'anno
- In relative clauses referring to something *undetermined* (often expressed by an indefinite pronoun like *nulla*, *comunque*, *qualsiasi*...) or to adjectives with restrictive value (*unico*, *solo*, *ultimo*

  > Non c'è nulla che mi piaccia
  >   Comunque vada, almeno ci siamo incontrati.
  >   Cerco un insegnante che mi faccia capire il congiuntivo!
  >   Giovanni è la sola persona che mi ascolti.
- With the *indirect interrogative clauses* when the answer is *unknown* or *uncertain*. [1]

  > Il cavaliere chiese alla dama se **volesse** essere accompagnata al suo castello.
  >   È inutile chiedersi perché i draghi **sono** in via d'estinzione.
- In certain forms of the *periodo ipotetico* ("if/then clauses"). I wrote an answer [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/8164/1818) with more details

  > Se volessi, sarei capace di usare il congiuntivo.

The subjunctive **is not used** when expressing certainty (as it is often the case for verbs of perception or for verbs expressing the action of making a statement):

> È indubbio che studiare è utile
>   Vedo che sei tornato a casa
>   Ho sempre detto che eri bravo

---

Finally, to look at your example sentences

> Aspetterò che torni come aspetto il sole

Here the clause *che torni* is at the subjunctive: it expresses a desire, so it falls into the first bullet point. In particular the verb *aspettare* always requires the subjunctive in the subordinate clause. In the grammars you can find long lists of such verbs.

> Ti giuro che l’attesa aumenta il desiderio

Here the clause expresses a strong certainty: the subjunctive cannot be used here and in fact the verb *aumenta* is at the indicative. Compare with

> Credo che l'attesa **aumenti** il desiderio

where an opinion is stated, and so the verb is at the subjunctive.

---

[1]  The subjunctive used to be mandatory in all indirect interrogative clauses, but the indicative and the conditional have been making more and more inroads into the common usage. When in doubt, use the subjunctive but don't be too surprised if you hear people using the indicative liberally in this context.

Comment: Suggestions to improve the explanation (that ended up more complicated than I wanted) are highly appreciated

Comment: Cannot thank you enough for your effort

Comment: @DenisNardin it would be nice to add the 2 additional rules about relative clauses and relative superlatives / adjectives with restrictive value, mentioned in https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10300/is-subjunctive-always-used-in-the-attributive-clause-of-a-superlative-expression

Comment: @AlanEvangelista I believe the one about relative superlatives is already present (it's the third bullet point), but I'll see if I can add the other one tomorrow. I don't want to clutter this too much though (there are many more rules, as you've probably discovered) since this is only intended as a first approximation.

Answer (score 4):

In the first sentence the verb is in the subjunctive mood: if, instead of a single person there are several, it would be

> Aspetterò che torniate come aspetto il sole

at least in standard Italian.

However, the text might use some colloquial register, where the subjunctive is often substituted with the indicative and it cannot be inferred from this single line, as the verb *tornare* has the same form for the second person singular in the present indicative and subjunctive:

> torno, torni, torna, torniamo, tornate, tornano (indicative)
>   torni, torni, torni, torniamo, torniate, tornino (subjunctive)

The subjunctive is required, because the action is set in the future. The second sentence has the present tense and it is about a *certainty*: the subjunctive would be wrong. If I swear to something, I can't have doubts.

Comment: It's fun, because reading the first sentence I automatically assumed the clause to be at the third person singular. Of course the text is ambiguous, so it could be either way...